# SolvePoly in opencv 1.0

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I am using open cv 1.0. In opencv 1.o there is not cvSolvePoly function. What can i use for this in opencv 1.0?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new version.